# Can I programmatically add my app to superuser.apk list without user prompt in android?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel

My device is rooted and when I execute the `su` command it displays a dialog for **superuser permission** and adds my application to the `superuser.apk` list.

What does the `superuser.apk` do? Can I programmatically add my app to the
`superuser.apk` list without prompting the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not add yourself to list without user prompt.

That is the reason of superuser.apk - to show the user prompt to disallow evil applications gaining root access.